# CSV lookup problem solved with CoffeeScript

Tags: csv, coffeescript

Source code with some test:

```
assert = require('assert')


compile_csv_search = (text, lookupKey)->
    [header, body...]= text.split('\n').filter(Boolean).map((el)->
        el.split(',')
    )
    col = header.indexOf(lookupKey)
    assert(col isnt -1)
    lookupIndex = body.reduce(
        (acc, row, i)->
            cell = row[col]
            acc[cell] = i
            return acc
        {}
    )
    return (lookupName)->
        rowNum = lookupIndex[lookupName]
        return body[rowNum].reduce(
            (acc, el, i)->
                acc[header[i]] = el
                return acc
            {}
        ) if rowNum?




# test one
(()->
    csvText = "ip,name,desc\n"+
        "10.49.1.4,server1,Main Server\n"+
        "10.52.5.1,server2,Backup Server\n"
    csv_by_name = compile_csv_search(
        csvText
        "name"
    )

    assert.deepEqual(
        csv_by_name("server2")
        {ip: "10.52.5.1", name: "server2", desc: "Backup Server"}
    )
    assert not csv_by_name("server9")?
)()
```

I think it is pretty descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

Your `lookupIndex` may not work as intended unless the value you're using for the lookup is unique across all rows. You'll always find the *last* row in the CSV data, since the reduce function that creates `lookupIndex` will overwrite any existing lookup key/value with a new row number. That may not be a problem, but it is a limitation in your function.

You're doing a few things that you don't strictly need in CoffeeScript:

- Explicit returns
- Parentheses around function arguments
- A "JS-style" IIFE, when CoffeeScript has the `do` keyword
- You can define multi-line strings in CoffeeScript; just use 3 quotes (like Python)
- CoffeeScript also has a `for..of` object iterator which would probably be more readable than your `reduce` calls (although semantically different)

Admittedly, the first 2 post are as much a question of context and preference. Sometimes you *do* need parentheses (e.g. when chaining function calls), and sometimes an explicit return is more readable. Still, though, your syntax seems a little funky in some places (for instance omitting commas in the call that to `compile_csv_list`, yet including the parentheses?)

In more general terms:

- You're mixing `snake_case` and `camelCase`. Just stick to `camelCase` as that's the JS (and thus CoffeeScript) convention. For instance you'll see that `assert.deepEqual` is camel-cased. Speaking of convention; 2 spaces of indentation is the most common rule.
- You're requiring `assert`, presumably for use in your tests - but you also use it in the function itself. That seems like a bad idea. Especially since you can just `throw` your own, possibly more detailed, exception whenever you want.
- You could consider checking the header line for the `lookupKey` before parsing the rest of the lines.
- I hope your CSV data is fairly easy to deal with; otherwise I'd find a full featured CSV parsing library, if I were you. Right now, you're just splitting on newlines and commas - but CSV may contain strings with commas in them, and which aren't "cell" delimiters. And a string may contain quotes - in which case the outer string has *two* quotes around it or something, if I recall correctly... CSV is a bizarre format with no simple rules for escaping things. The only real way to parse it, if you want to be thorough, is to go byte by byte; a regex just won't cut it.

Anyway, here's a version with some style changes. The only functional difference is that it doesn't use `assert` in the function itself.

```
compileCSVSearch = (csv, lookupKey)->
  [header, rows...] = csv.split("\n").filter(Boolean).map (line) -> line.split ","

  columnIndex = header.indexOf lookupKey
  throw "Can't find a '#{lookupKey}' column" if column is -1 # consider throwin ag proper Error obj

  lookupTable = {}
  for row, i in rows
    value = rows[columnIndex]
    lookupTable[value] = i

  (lookupValue) ->
    index = lookupTable[lookupValue]
    return unless index?
    copy = {}
    copy[key] = value for own key, value of rows[index]
    copy


# Tests

do ->
  assert = require "assert"

  csvText = """ip,name,desc
               10.49.1.4,server1,Main Server
               10.52.5.1,server2,Backup Server\n"""

  csvByName = compileCSVSearch csvText, "name"

  assert.deepEqual csvByName("server2"),
    ip: "10.52.5.1",
    name: "server2",
    desc: "Backup Server"

  assert.equal csvByName("server9"), undefined
```

Comment: thanks for great comment! I use assert as a predicate http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assertion_(software_development)

Comment: @kharandziuk I figured that was why you had `assert` there. But requiring a library that's really mostly aimed at testing seems like overkill compared to a simple `throw ... if ...`. If JS/CS just had a builtin `assert` function/macro/keyword/whatever then by all means use it - unfortunately, if doesn't. So that's an entire dependency that has to be required, versus writing a single line. I'd pick the single line :)